# How to integrate Sentry with .NET 6.0 Worker Service?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, sentry, worker-service

I integrated `Sentry` with .NET Core 6.0 **Worker Service** this way:

NuGet: **Sentry 3.17.1**

```cs
// Program.cs:

using Sentry;

var sentryDsn = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENTRY_DSN");
using (SentrySdk.Init(o =>
{
    o.Dsn = sentryDsn;
    o.Debug = true;
    o.TracesSampleRate = 1.0;
}))
{
    IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .Build();

    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

```cs
// Worker.cs:

namespace demo_heroku_sentry_worker;
using Sentry;

public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

            try
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Exception inside of worker service");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SentrySdk.CaptureException(e);
            }

            await Task.Delay(10000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

This is working in some way because I see the manually captured error on my Sentry Dashboard. However I'm concerned about these warning messages I receive on the Application Output:

```
      Worker running at: 05/11/2022 15:51:06 +02:00
  Debug: Failed to report an error on a session because there is none active.
   Info: Capturing event.
  Debug: Running processor on exception: Exception inside of worker service
  Debug: Creating SentryStackTrace. isCurrentStackTrace: False.
  Debug: Running main event processor on: Event abb5b3e2ee3a4dbd***********
   Info: Envelope queued up: 'abb5b3e2ee3a4dbda50ef***********'
  Debug: Envelope abb5b3e2ee3a4dbda50e*********** handed off to transport. #1 in queue.
  Debug: Envelope 'abb5b3e2ee3a4dbda50efe7***********' sent successfully. Payload:
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- There's nothing wrong with the way you originally implemented it.  The debug logs you showed are just Sentry doing it's normal work.  If you don't want to see them, don't set `o.Debug = true;`
- You have code that manually reads the `SENTRY_DSN` environment variable and sets it to `o.Dsn` during initialization.  That's redundant because the SDK will *already* look for that environment variable if you don't pass a DSN in code.  Do one or the other, but not both.
- If you were concerned about the message `"Failed to report an error on a session because there is none active."` - That's just saying that you haven't started a session, so Sentry's "[Release Health](https://docs.sentry.io/product/releases/health/)" feature won't work.  You can enable it either by manually calling `SentrySdk.StartSession();` and `SentrySdk.EndSession();` at appropriate places in your application, or by setting `o.AutoSessionTracking = true;` which is easier.  The latter will start a session when the Sentry SDK is initialized, and end it when it is disposed.
- While nothing wrong with the approach you showed, you would get better functionality out of the [logging integration](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/extensions-logging/).  The example code [here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/9f7caf11366ef2d73346e7c176ff2478a6904455/samples/Sentry.Samples.GenericHost/Program.cs) shows how to use it with the generic host.  Use the nuget package [`Sentry.Extensions.Logging`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentry.Extensions.Logging).

Putting it all together :

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.AddSentry(o =>
        {
            // o.Dsn = "(only if not using the env var)"; 
            o.TracesSampleRate = 1.0;
            o.AutoSessionTracking = true;
        });
    }
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();
```

Answer (score -3):

It seems that as per the [documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/aspnetcore/) the correct way to integrate Sentry with .NET (Core) 6.0 is the following: (changes indicated `<--`)

```
// Program.cs

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var sentryDsn = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SENTRY_DSN");  // <--
builder.WebHost.UseSentry(sentryDsn);                              // <--

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSentryTracing();                                            // <--

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

It does catch unhandled API call errors and it does not print any warnings on the output console.

Comment: Irrelevant answer, worker doesn't have WebHost