# Setup Sentry with .Net Worker Service

Tags: .net, sentry, .net-core-service-worker

I've seen how to integrate Sentry with a .Net web app and with a console app.  But for a service worker, where the bootstrapping of the app is done with

```cs
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
  .UseWindowsService(...)
  .ConfigureServices(...)
```

instead of

```cs
IHost host = Host.CreateHostBuilder(args)
  .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder=>
  {
    webBuilder.UseSentry();
    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
  });
```

I have tried using the `Sentry.AspNetCore` package and the `Sentry` package, and boostrapping Sentry with different methods, including `.ConfigureWebHostDefaults` but that leads to the service not working (I get this error: `No application configured. Please specify an application via IWebHostBuilder.UseStartup, IWebHostBuilder.Configure, or specifying the startup assembly via StartupAssemblyKey in the web host configuration.`)

I've seen also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72202391/how-to-integrate-sentry-with-net-6-0-worker-service) but the answer given is not a service worker anymore.

So the question is: how can I use Sentry in a Service Worker app (that will become a Windows Service) ?

Thanks.

Comment: I kept trying and finally found something: In `.ConfigureServices` action I can add `services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder=>{ loggingBuilder.AddSentry((sentryOptions)=>{sentryOptions.Dns = ...});`  -- just wondering if that's equivalent as the asp.net helper functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Sentry.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sentry.Extensions.Logging) NuGet package, and then add Sentry through the logging integration:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
// ...

.ConfigureLogging(loggingBuilder) =>
{
    loggingBuilder.AddSentry();
})

// ...
```

There's a sample application in the `sentry-dotnet` repository [here](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/main/samples/Sentry.Samples.GenericHost/Program.cs) that shows that, along with some additional things - though it was made some time ago and needs to be updated to simplify.

From the comment on your question, it looks like you already found this yourself.  Yes, it's the correct way to do this for the time being.  Eventually we will have a simpler API that uses `IHostBuilder` directly (see [issue #190](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/190)).

You also asked:

> ... just wondering if that's equivalent as the asp.net helper functions?

The ASP.NET Core integration *starts* with that, and then adds things that are specific for ASP.NET Core, such as a middleware component that automatically instruments each HTTP request/response.  Such additions wouldn't be applicable in the service you described, but you could add [custom instrumentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/performance/instrumentation/custom-instrumentation/) for your own features if you wanted to.